# How do you arrange ImageViews and TextViews dynamically to Linear Layout in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I've got a fragment from which users select features their rooms have (fig.1 below) and these are stored in the back-end as boolean values i.e. true if set and false otherwise.

[image: fragment used to capture room features]

The XML for the fragment:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"

 <!-- none core xml formatting and views -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_top"
            android:id="@+id/details_amenities_layout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_bic_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_bic"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_bic_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_bic_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/add_room_bic_imageview" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_entrance_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_entrance"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_entrance_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_entrance_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_toilet_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_toilet"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_toilet_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_toilet_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_kitchen_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_kitchen"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_kitchen_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_kitchen_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_parking_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_parking"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_parking_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_parking_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/add_room_parking_imageview" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_wifi_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_wi_fi"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_wifi_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_wifi_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_secure_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_secure"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_secure_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_secure_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/add_room_secure_imageview"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_furnished_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_furnished"
                        style="@style/amenities_image_style"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_furnished_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_furnished_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/add_room_furnished_imageview"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_borehole_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_borehole"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_borehole_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_borehole_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_prezesa_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_zesa"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_zesa_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_prezesa_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/add_room_prezesa_imageview"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_wardrobe_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_wardrobe"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_wardrobe_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_wardrobe_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_prewater_imageview"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_prewater"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/add_room_water_amenity"
                        android:id="@+id/add_room_prewater_label"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/add_room_prewater_imageview"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/add_room_prewater_imageview"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/add_room_prewater_imageview"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

  <!-- none core views -->

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/add_room_step3_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_done_white_48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Naturally the selected features differ thus the number of views is not constant obtained from the back-end. I am able to retrieve the set features and instantiate the correct views in Java i.e. if there are 5 set features comprising **BIC**, **Wifi**, **Kitchen** etc, I am able to determine these and set the necessary Image resources and Text.

Question now is how do I arrange the views obtained to replicate the layout above using Java code as I can only know the features set after querying the back-end. Desired end result has to look like the image below. Hope it makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Use a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager instead. It is way much easier.

Comment: Use it where and  how? I have tried adding a RecyclerView just before the 'Amenities' label as this is where the dynamic views are being presented but with no luck of displaying the views. Any pointers are most welcome